# Как правильно писать предложение в кавычках?

Tags: синтаксис

Скажите, пожалуйста, если в предложении идет цитата в кавычках, причем то, что находится в кавычках является полноценным предложением, нужно ли ставить точку и в конце предложения в кавычках, и после кавычек, если они идут друг за другом? Например: ".".

Answer (score 2):

Нет, в этом случае ставится только точка после кавычек.У Лопатина:§ 159. При сочетании разных знаков препинания с  кавычками действуют правила:

1) перед закрывающей кавычкой ставятся знаки  вопросительный, восклицательный и многоточие, если они относятся к словам, заключенным в кавычки: «Как ни грустно в этом непонятном мире, но он всё же прекрасен!» — эти слова И. Бунина 
К. Паустовский предпослал одному из своих сочинений; Когда Багрицкий читал пушкинское «Для берегов отчизны дольной...», его нельзя было слушать без волнения; если же эти знаки  относятся ко всему предложению с включенными в него закавыченными словами, то ставятся в конце предложения, в том числе после закрывающей кавычки: Пришвин однажды написал о себе (в частном письме), что он «поэт, распятый на кресте 
прозы»!

2) перед закрывающей кавычкой не ставятся точка, запятая, точка с запятой, двоеточие, тире; по условиям контекста эти знаки ставятся после кавычки: В газете был напечатан рассказ Бунина «Легкое дыхание»; Рядом с зарницей стоит в одном поэтическом ряду слово «заря» — одно из прекраснейших слов русского языка (Пауст.);

3) если перед закрывающей кавычкой стоит знак  вопросительный, восклицательный или многоточие (и на этом предложение заканчивается), то те же знаки, необходимые по условиям всего предложения, не повторяются после закрывающей кавычки; неодинаковые знаки (перед кавычкой и после кавычки) ставятся; ср.: «Вы читали романы «Что делать?» и «Кто виноват ?»; Кто не знает великолепных слов А. Блока: «Сотри случайные черты. И ты увидишь — мир прекрасен...»?; Неужели вы не прочитали роман «Что делать?»!